# \edlineref produces wrong visual cross-reference when label set by \doinsidelinehook

Tags: cross-referencing, reledmac

I need to produce unique labels for each line of a text edition because I cite many many lines at random in my treatment. Also, I hyperlink the cross-references for ease of use by the reader.

In the MWE below, I have used the `\doinsidelinehook` feature to generate unique labels automatically once the line number has been set (as per documentation). The links seem to work as expected as far as I can tell (clicking appears to take me to the right place) but there is a problem: output does not match the line number.

[image]

I am wondering what I have done incorrectly or how to override the output to give the reader the correct visual information.

Note: removing the `\doinsidelinehook` does gets correct the visual output error but of course then I don't have meaningful auto-generated labels.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
    \firstlinenum{1}\linenumincrement{1}
    \newcommand{\nochange}[1]{#1}   % dummy command
    \Xwraplinenumannotationref{\nochange} % disable \textsuperscript of annotations
    % generate unique labels for each line
    \makeatletter
    \doinsidelinehook{\edlabel{L:\the\line@num}}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

This file demonstrates hyperref links to reledmac lines.

%NB documentation says "\annotref" but it seems to be "\annotationref"
\begin{enumerate}
\item Jump to \edlineref{L:1}\annotationref{L:1}
      (first line on first page; this should read `1').
\item Jump to \edlineref{L:2}\annotationref{L:2}
      (last line on first page; this should read `2').
\item Jump to \edlineref{L:3}\annotationref{L:3}
      (first line on second page; this should read `3X').
\item Now let's jump to the last line of the text using a
      `normal' label, \edlineref{L:test}. We expect `5'.
\end{enumerate}

\beginnumbering
\pstart Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Mauris dapibus scelerisque imperdiet. Aliquam
gravida elementum enim facilisis tincidunt.\pend
\clearpage% makes it easy to see whether the jumps work

\pstart \linenumannotation{X}Nullam vel nisi ut lacus
luctus malesuada ut vitae lectus. Donec sed mauris
aliquet, congue est sed, tincidunt nulla. Ut malesuada,
urna vitae luctus volutpat, nulla mauris tincidunt
nibh, nec malesuada justo ipsum tempor\edlabel{L:test}
justo.\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

---

Another example which more closely parallels actual intended usage (not as minimal but addresses the concern of wrapping lines mentioned in the comment. The annotation doesn't work at all for some reason.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
    \firstlinenum{1}\linenumincrement{1}
    \newcommand{\nochange}[1]{#1}
    \Xwraplinenumannotation{\nochange}
    \Xwraplinenumannotationref{\nochange}

\usepackage{reledpar} 
    \setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.49\textwidth}
    \setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.49\textwidth} 
    \firstlinenum*{1}
    \linenumincrement*{1}
    \setstanzaindents{1,0}
    \setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{1em}
    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
    \AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}
    % generate unique labels for each line
    \makeatletter
    \doinsidelineLhook{\edlabel{\text\the\line@num}}
    \makeatother

\newcommand{\text}{}

\begin{document}

This file demonstrates hyperref links to reledmac lines.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Jump to \edlineref{1:1}\annotationref{1:1}
      (first line of text 1).
\item Jump to \edlineref{1:2}\annotationref{1:2}
      (last line of text 1).
\item Jump to \edlineref{2:3}\annotationref{2:3}
      (first line of text 2/second page).
\item Now let's try some normal labels:
     \edlineref{test1}\annotationref{test1} and \edlineref{test2}\annotationref{test2}.
\end{enumerate}

\renewcommand{\text}{1:}
Text \text

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\begin{astanza}
one short line one&
\edlabel{test1}\linenumannotation{X}one short line two\&
\end{astanza}
\pausenumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\autopar
\noindent first translation\pend
\pausenumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\clearpage% makes it easy to see whether the jumps work

\renewcommand{\text}{2:}
Text \text

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\resumenumbering
\begin{astanza}
two short line one&
\edlabel{test2}two short line two&
\skipnumbering continued\&
\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\resumenumbering
\autopar
\noindent second translation\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The main problem is that `\doinsidelinehook` is down when the line number have been fixed for the typesetting, but not for cross-referencing. I try to find a way for your problem.

Comment: An other problem is that the time \doinsidelinehook is called is not the same as the main content of \pstart...\pend. So the value of the automatic label will be wrong.

Comment: In any case, I can't undertand how you could use your automtica labnel, as line breaking can change when you edit your texts / your geometry setting.

Comment: Hi and thanks. Actually, in my particular case, my lines are guaranteed not to change: every one of them is shorter (by force) than a full line, so once I've set them up they will never change. An alternative solution would be if I could write the actual line numbers out to an auxiliary file, then I could write a script to retrieve them from there and write the labels in a separate pass of my own, with another script. More work, but acceptable.

Comment: but if the line are determined, why do you need cross-ref? You could use fixed value.

Comment: I just added another example. The issue is that I want to do something like `\linkto{<text no.>}{<line no.>}` to an arbitrary place. If I have to create each label by hand (L2:3x for example) it is a long process and very error prone (every text restarts the numbering but some texts have continuous lines, some restart by section, some have annotations). Somehow I want to grab the numbers generated by `reledmac` (and the annotations when there are any). (I can send a live PDF by PM if it helps.)

Comment: @Maïeul Actually there may be a (safer?) solution outside the package.... just because of the structure of the text editions in this case. Checking this now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71366/discussion-between-k-g-feuerherm-and-maieul).